When does $\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+x^t\sin^2x}\mathrm dx$ converge?
I wonder what $t$ makes $\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+x^t\sin^2x}\mathrm dx$ converge.
In a calculus textbook, it is proved that it converge when $t=4$ but disconverge when $t=2$.
I tried Mathematica, Wolfram Alpha and Desmos, but none helps me.
I plotted the function respect to t, but it looks like a mess.
Plot[NIntegrate[1/(1 + x^t Sin[x]^2), {x, 0, Infinity}], {t, 1.95, 2.05}]



Thank you very much.

Clarification requested: "In a calculus textbook, it is proved that it converge when $k=4$ but disconverge when $k=2$." : Did you intend ...when $~\color{red}{t}=4~$ but ... when $~\color{red}{t}=2~?$

@user2661923 Yes, I've corrected it, thx!

Study the series $$\sum \int\limits_0^\pi{dx\over 1+(x+n\pi)^t\sin^2x}$$ and use $\sin x\sim x$ near $0$ and $\sin x\sim \pi -x$ near $\pi.$
